# My Android Phone Keeps Telling me that it is on Silent

Tags: notifications

Ever since I updated my mobile to Android Version 6.01 I get notifications regarding my phone being on silent... This only happens when I plug it onto charge.

Its rather annoying that it keeps telling me this for two reasons:

A: The phone is on Vibrate not Silent

B:I chose to put it on vibrate I don't understand why it needs to keep telling me this.

The same applies for when I leave battery saver mode on, it tells me its on and that the performance is effected. I leave it on battery saver for a reason...

Is there any way to disable these "Helpful" Messages in the settings as I cannot for the life of me find a setting that references this, even in the developer mode. My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S5 Mini if that provides any assistance...

Comment: Not on stock... You would need a custom ROM, although root and Xposed may work as well but I'm not familiar with a module that has these specific features.

Comment: Does this mean its a feature of the OS itself?

Comment: Somewhat, yes, the battery saver portion I think, but AOSP is not as intrusive... But Samsung adds their own pieces to Android that are in the OS itself, these "features" are part of that.

Comment: ah see... I have little to no experience with making changes to the OS. I am interested to know how I would go about modifying this on my phone mind.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s5-mini

Answer (score 1):

I went into Samsung+ app, went to Settings and turned off Diagnostic Notifications.  Have not seen the notification since.

Comment: I do not have a Samsung Plus App, does this go by a different name?

Answer (score -1):

Samsung Galaxy. Following Rick's tip that it was a Samsung app, I disabled the app in the app manager. That worked for me.